# Как писать заявление

Tags: документы

Как правильнее писать шапку заявления: "Такому-то ОТ такого-то заявление" или "Такому-то такого-то заявление"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-всякому можно. Вариант "такому-то такого-то" - в обшем-то архаичен, но сейчас продолжает использоваться.

Answer (score 0):

В учебных пособиях: и школьных, и для студентов - вариант **заявление чьё?** предлагается как единственно верный.

Comment: Посмотреть бы на эти учебники.
ПОтыкался сейчас случайным образом в некоторый базы образцов заявлений - вариант "от кого" преобладает.
Впрочем, в скором времени и то и другое, видимо, отомрёт за не надобностью в связи с повсеместным внедрением бланков автоматизированного учета. Там обычно есть графа "заявитель", и самому заявителю не придётся ломать голову над формой.

Comment: Это точно. Из учебников...Учебники по культуре речи для вузов. Под рукой только учебное пособие по издательской программе 300 лучших учебников для высшей школы. Изд-во Питер 2006 (РУсский язык и культура речи). Посмотрела на "Грамоте" - оба варианта даются как равноправные. Что касается норм - учебники всегда консервативны.